Including Headers Causes my OS to Fail at the Boot Stage
I'm building an operating system, but I can't include external modules. This is a must-have for any nontrivial project. I've tried many things, but this is the current iteration, and the simplest one. I'm using the limine C++ template, which you can examine here: https://github.com/limine-bootloader/limine-cpp-template
I have a header called graphics.hpp, which looks like this.
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

namespace kint { namespace graphics
// namespace kint::graphics
{
    typedef std::uint32_t index_t;
    typedef std::uint32_t color_t;

    inline std::uint32_t width = 0;
    inline volatile std::uint32_t *vram = nullptr;

    void init(void);

    void drawPixel(index_t, index_t, color_t);
}}

I implement this header with limine, like this.
#include <cstdint>
#include <limine.h>

#include "graphics.hpp"

void kint::graphics::init(void) {
    volatile limine_framebuffer_request request = { .id = LIMINE_FRAMEBUFFER_REQUEST, .revision = 0, .response = nullptr };
    width = request.response->framebuffers[0]->pitch / 4;
    vram = static_cast<volatile std::uint32_t*>(request.response->framebuffers[0]->address);
}

void kint::graphics::drawPixel(index_t x, index_t y, color_t color) {
    vram[x * width + y] = color;
}

These are in a folder called kint. Then, I add this into the limine C++ template, as follows.
// ...
#include "kint/graphics.hpp"
// ...
extern "C" void _start() {
    if (LIMINE_BASE_REVISION_SUPPORTED == false) hcf();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; &__init_array[i] != __init_array_end; i++) __init_array[i]();
    if (framebuffer_request.response == nullptr || framebuffer_request.response->framebuffer_count < 1) hcf();

    kint::graphics::init();

    // Draw the diagonal line
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        kint::graphics::drawPixel(i, i, 0x00FFFFFF);

    // We're done, just hang...
    hcf();
}

This all compiles, but when I startup my OS, it creates a Qemu VM, I boot it, and my OS won't boot. I just get kicked back to the bootloader when I try.
I've tried a million and one things. I rewrote all files in question, restarted the whole project, git cloned the limine-cpp-template repository and worked from there to ensure no copying errors, and I tried the Qemu debugger (which has been useless so far). I've also tried using G++ -fmodules-ts and the module system, manually including the header (i.e. copy-pasting it into the main file), and more. When I copy the C++ file in, however, it does work properly. I've also tried messing with the GNUmakefile, to no avail.

To clarify, kint is short for "kernel internals," and is a set of modules containing low-level utilities used by the kernel, atop which I'll build the full thing.

How can anyone be sure of that given what happened with the last kint?

But seriously, if you have to make a comment like that, odds are good the example's not going to be complete enough.

@user4581301 I don't have to, I was just using a weird holdover identifier, and wanted to clear it up for readability.
